# Ionic 4 background blinks and tap delay

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

This is my first application using ionic4 and there is something weird happening. When I tap on any link, there is delay and the entire background blinks before it loads the page. Here is a video showing this weird behave: https://youtu.be/NqoOMQYyr4k

For reference, here is the code for the pages:

On the **global.scss** i have this property to setup the background

```
ion-content {
  --background: #000 url('./assets/images/main-bg.png') no-repeat center center / cover;
}
```

**news.page.ts**

```
import { News } from './news.model';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NewsService } from '../services/news.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-news',
  templateUrl: './news.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./news.page.scss'],
})
export class NewsPage implements OnInit {

  news: any;

  constructor(private newsService: NewsService, private router: Router, private navController: NavController) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.news = this.newsService.getAllEvents();
  }

  go(id: string) {
    this.navController.navigateForward('news/' + id);
  }
}
```

**news.page.html**

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-toolbar color="grey">
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title style="color: #524A4A!important">News</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>


<ion-content>
  <ion-grid padding class="margin-logo-header">
    <ion-row>
      <div>
        <h2>Noticias HD Friends</h2>
      </div>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>


  <ion-card color="grey" *ngFor="let news of news | async">
    <ion-nav-pop (click)="go(news.id)" >
      <ion-img src="{{news.picture}}"></ion-img>
      <ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-title>{{ news.title }}</ion-card-title>
      </ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-content>
        <p>{{ news.subtitle }}</p>
      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-nav-pop>

  </ion-card>


</ion-content>
```

**news.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { News } from '../news/news.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NewsService {

  NODE = 'news/';
  news: AngularFireList<News[]>;

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  getAllEvents() {
    const localNews = this.db.list(this.NODE);
    return localNews.valueChanges();
  }

  getNews(id: string) {
    return this.db.object(this.NODE + id);
  }
}
```

Is this a bug because it's a beta or is this something I messed up?

Thanks guys

---

**UPDATE 1**
This seems to be a bug on ionic framework. As soon as I get something I'll post here for future reference.

Comment: Do you need to use the navController, why not navigate with the router, would that work better?

Comment: If I use the router, there is no page transition animation. :/

Comment: ion-router-outlet wraps then angular router with animations, you may have to test on the device to see this, I know with <ion-router-outlet [animated]="true" ></ion-router-outlet> in your app.component.html  will show movement forward and backward between pages

Comment: hey @JayOrdway I tried that. Didn't work. :( The issue on github is currently under investigation.

Comment: please discuss the routing another place. I have too get this error when using video background. And it blink more than your video which you sent.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: @iconio, did you get any solution for this?